# How to execute insert query and returns the new row's Primary Key

Tags: python, mysql, flask, peewee

I've tried the [flask-peewee / peewee](https://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/api.html#InsertQuery) example. the query runs sucessfully but It doesn't return the new row PK.

Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/api/merchant/invoice/',  methods=['POST'])
def merchantInvoice():
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.form['checkin_id']:
        active = checkin_details.select().where(checkin_details.is_active==True)
        try:
            checkin = active.where(checkin_details.id == request.form['checkin_id']).get()
            sale=Sales(
                checkin_id=checkin.id,
                merchant_id =checkin.merchant_id,
                created_at=datetime.datetime.now(),
                sale_amount=request.form['amount'],
                user_id=checkin.user_id
            )
            sale.save()
            return sale_id=sale.id
```

Comment: Your example link shows an `InsertQuery` that will return the primary key - perhaps you should try using that instead?

Comment: @xiankai I did, it says InsertQuery not defined :)

Comment: The code you've posted is not valid python (you cannot say `return sale_id=sale_id`). Please edit the code with valid python that actually runs. Additionally, add a print statement after `save.save()` and ENSURE that `sale.id` is not being filled.